# CSS classes: base+additional. How to define?

Tags: css

I have a div:

```
    <div class="navigation mainPage"></div>
```

I need to specify that: every DIV that has a class "navigation" AND class "mainPage" should have "width: 999px".

Is this possible?
thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
.navigation.mainPage { width: 999px; }
```

Comment: I have read an article that other browsers(specially old browsers don't support multiple css in a single element. Here is the link http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/qt/tipcssmulticlas.htm

Comment: I meant multiple css classes in a single element.

Comment: This does not work in IE6, not as intended. In IE6, this selector matches on the mainPage class only. See http://so.piskvor.org/1537692/ for a test case.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
.navigation.mainPage { width: 999px; }
```

but this **doesn't work in IE6**. You can try to go around by doing

```
<div class="navigation navigation-mainPage"></div>
```

and then CSS

```
.navigation-mainPage { width: 999px; }
```

Even though this isn't the nicest solution, but I don't know of any other way around it.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
.navigation, .mainPage{ width:999px; overflow:hidden;}
```

Comment: That would make everything with the class navigation have a width of 999px. They only want the width set to 999px with the div has navigation and mainpage classes set.

Comment: They are classes not IDs so they should be `.navigation` and `.mainPage`.

Comment: #navigation means 'id="navigation"', not 'class="navigation"'; also, comma means "OR", as in "navigation or mainPage or both"

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what's AND and OR in CSS?

Comment: In my browser tests (IE8,FF3,Opera10), it seems that Nimbuz and Darth are correct, but see the IE6 caveat mentioned by Darth.

Comment: re OR: See http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp , header Grouping. E.g. ".class1, .class2" would match elements with class1 OR class2, whereas ".class1.class2" would only match elements with class1 AND class2, and ".class1 .class2" would match elements with class2 inside elements with class1.

Comment: Now, I know thank you very much for that info, I will note it.